# My realtime database of Firebase is not loading any data on the console also for rules

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Chrome browser and my adblocker is of:

[image]

This circular loading indicator is showing on the screen, what to do?

Comment: Readers will probably need to see some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

something is continuously updating. **Stop your frontend project and debug it**